# Serial correlation test in panelvar package in R

Tags: r, panel-data, gmm, autocorrelation

I am using the `pvargmm` function from the `panelvar` package developed by Sigmund and Ferstl to estimate a GMM model. As far as I could see from the package's PDF file, there is not a built-in function to conduct a **serial correlation (AR(2)) test**. Does anyone have any suggestions regarding how this can be done?